# Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.Unsat

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, maven, jpa

I'm new to coding and I was creating a sample springboot application. In get mapping I wanted to display all the items. I'm using JAVAX persistence. but I'm getting an error like

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file [C:\Users\TheCanner\Desktop\exchangers\exchangers\target\classes\com\ecommerce\exchangers\controller\HomeController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'itemServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\TheCanner\Desktop\exchangers\exchangers\target\classes\com\ecommerce\exchangers\Servises\impl\ItemServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'itemsRepo' defined in com.ecommerce.exchangers.repository.ItemsRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.ecommerce.exchangers.entity.Items"

Controller file

```
package com.ecommerce.exchangers.controller;

import com.ecommerce.exchangers.Servises.ItemService;
import com.ecommerce.exchangers.payload.ItemsDto;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")

public class HomeController {

    private ItemService itemService;

    public HomeController(ItemService itemService) {
        this.itemService = itemService;
    }

    @PostMapping("home")
    public ResponseEntity<ItemsDto> addItem(@RequestBody ItemsDto itemsDto){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(itemService.addItem(itemsDto), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

Entity file

```
package com.ecommerce.exchangers.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Table(name = "Items", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "itemId" }) })

public class Items {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer itemId;

    @Column(name = "Item Category", nullable = false)
private Integer itemPrice;

@Column(name = "Item Category", nullable = false)
private Double itemRating;

@Column(name = "Item Category", nullable = false)
private String itemName;

@Column(name = "Item Category", nullable = false)
private String itemCategory;
}
```

payload file

```
package com.ecommerce.exchangers.payload;

import lombok.Data;

@Data

public class ItemsDto {
    private int itemId;
    private int itemPrice;
    private double itemRating;
    private String itemName;
    private String itemCategory;

}
```

repository file

```
package com.ecommerce.exchangers.repository;

import com.ecommerce.exchangers.entity.Items;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ItemsRepo extends JpaRepository<Items,Integer> {
}
```

service impl file

```
package com.ecommerce.exchangers.Servises.impl;

import com.ecommerce.exchangers.Servises.ItemService;
import com.ecommerce.exchangers.entity.Items;
import com.ecommerce.exchangers.payload.ItemsDto;
import com.ecommerce.exchangers.repository.ItemsRepo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

    private ItemsRepo itemsRepo;

    public ItemServiceImpl(ItemsRepo itemsRepo) {
        this.itemsRepo = itemsRepo;
    }

// Here you have to convert entity into  DTO
    private ItemsDto mapToDTO(Items items){
        ItemsDto itemsDto = new ItemsDto();
       itemsDto.setItemId(items.getItemId());
       itemsDto.setItemName(items.getItemName());
       itemsDto.setItemCategory(items.getItemCategory());
       itemsDto.setItemPrice(items.getItemPrice());
       itemsDto.setItemRating(items.getItemRating());
       return itemsDto;
    }
// Here you have to convert entity into  DTO
    private Items mapToEntity(ItemsDto itemsDto){
        Items items = new Items();
        items.setItemId(itemsDto.getItemId());
        items.setItemName(itemsDto.getItemName());
        items.setItemCategory(itemsDto.getItemCategory());
        items.setItemPrice(itemsDto.getItemPrice());
        items.setItemRating(itemsDto.getItemRating());
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemsDto addItem(ItemsDto itemsDto) {
        Items newItem;
        newItem = mapToEntity(itemsDto);
        Items newItem2 = itemsRepo.save(newItem);
        ItemsDto DtoResponse;
        DtoResponse = mapToDTO(newItem2);
        return DtoResponse;
    }
}
```

Servises file

```
package com.ecommerce.exchangers.Servises;

import com.ecommerce.exchangers.payload.ItemsDto;

public interface ItemService {
    ItemsDto addItem(ItemsDto itemsDto);
}
```

springBootApplication file

```
package com.ecommerce.exchangers;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ExchangersApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExchangersApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecommproj?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC

spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

#hibernate property
#MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

#Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ecommerce</groupId>
    <artifactId>exchangers</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>exchangers</name>
    <description>Demo project using Spring Boot Rest API, MySQL and Kafka (JVM)</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

errors are like this ( and I also mentioned that above)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Problem is that spring is unable to detect JPA repositories. Can you try creating a configuration class and annotate it with `@Configuration` and `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"<repositories package name>"})`. Remove the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation on entity class.

Comment: where I have to add that annotation and what is the differences between basePackage and repository package ?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa). Hope it clarify's your doubts :)